# Rails rspec set subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, subdomain, specifications

I am using rSpec for testing my application.  In my application controller I have a method like so:

```
def set_current_account
  @current_account ||= Account.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomains.first)
end
```

Is it possible to set the request.subdomain in my spec?  Maybe in the before block?  I am new to rSpec so any advice on this would be great thanks.

Eef

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I figured out how to sort this issue.

In my before block in my specs I simply added:

```
before(:each) do
  @request.host = "#{mock_subdomain}.example.com"
end
```

This setups up the request.subdomains.first to be the value of the mock_subdomain.

Hope someone finds this useful as its not explained very well anywhere else on the net.

Comment: one small tip - request is available as a method as well as an instance variable. It's probably better to access it via the method, to keep a little distance between you and the underlying RSpec code.

Comment: @lulalala `request.host = "#{mock_subdomain}.example.com"`

Comment: This is not working with me. I also added my subdomain, api, to /etc/hosts as such: api.example.com, and I still get the no route error. Any ideas?

Comment: Also I'm running on Rails 3.

Comment: Make sure you DONT do 'request.host'.  It must be an instance variable, '@request.host' in order to work properly.

Comment: For **Feature Specs** with Capybara use `Capybara.default_host` as noted by Chris Peters below.

Answer (score 60):

I know this is a relatively old question, but I've found that this depends on what kind of test you're running. I'm also running Rails 4 and RSpec 3.2, so I'm sure some things have changed since this question was asked.

**Request Specs**

```
before { host! "#{mock_subdomain}.example.com" }
```

**Feature Specs with Capybara**

```
before { Capybara.default_host = "http://#{mock_subdomain}.example.com" }
after  { Capybara.default_host = "http://www.example.com" }
```

I usually create modules in `spec/support` that look something like this:

```
# spec/support/feature_subdomain_helpers.rb
module FeatureSubdomainHelpers
  # Sets Capybara to use a given subdomain.
  def within_subdomain(subdomain)
    before { Capybara.default_host = "http://#{subdomain}.example.com" }
    after  { Capybara.default_host = "http://www.example.com" }
    yield
  end
end

# spec/support/request_subdomain_helpers.rb
module RequestSubdomainHelpers
  # Sets host to use a given subdomain.
  def within_subdomain(subdomain)
    before { host! "#{subdomain}.example.com" }
    after  { host! "www.example.com" }
    yield
  end
end
```

Include in `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...

  # Extensions
  config.extend FeatureSubdomainHelpers, type: :feature
  config.extend RequestSubdomainHelpers, type: :request
end
```

Then you can call within your spec like so:

```
feature 'Admin signs in' do
  given!(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :admin) }

  within_subdomain :admin do
    scenario 'with valid credentials' do
      # ...
    end

    scenario 'with invalid password' do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

In rails 3 everything I tried to manually set the host didn't work, but looking the code I noticed how nicely they parsed the path you pass to the request helpers like `get`.
Sure enough if your controller goes and fetches the user mentioned in the subdomain and stores it as `@king_of_the_castle`

```
it "fetches the user of the subomain" do
  get "http://#{mock_subdomain}.example.com/rest_of_the_path"
  assigns[:king_of_the_castle].should eql(User.find_by_name mock_subdomain)
end
```

Comment: Whether or not this is the official way to do it in Rails 3, adding the host directly to the path as demonstrated by ilpoldo worked for me.

Comment: This does not work in controllers specs. You cannot do `get "path"`. It will interpret that as the action. You must do `get :action_name` only for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, the one above is a snippet from a request spec.

Comment: In a controller I'd probably try to use the router the pass the subdomain as a param to the controller and then use something like `get :index, :user='ilpoldo'` in the controller spec. I'm not sure if it helps, but I have this example at hand: https://gist.github.com/ilpoldo/6052044.

Answer (score 2):

- Rspec - 3.6.0
- Capybara - 2.15.1

Chris Peters' answer worked for me for Request specs, but for Feature specs, I had to make the following changes:

**rails_helper:**

```
Capybara.app_host = 'http://lvh.me'
Capybara.always_include_port = true
```

**feature_subdomain_helpers:**

```
module FeatureSubdomainHelpers
    def within_subdomain(subdomain)
        before { Capybara.app_host = "http://#{subdomain}.lvh.me" }
        after  { Capybara.app_host = "http://lvh.me" }
        yield
    end
end
```