# Rails: How to test subdomains with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, subdomain

I am developing an application that with rely heavily on subdomains. It has an application embedded in the application (a module) that will be a backend to administer the application. Let's name it kong.

I have this code in my routes file:

```
constraints :subdomain => "kong" do
  scope :module => "kong", :as => "kong" do
    resources :clients
  end
end
```

How can I test this route so that when I write something like the following it fetches from the subdomain and only from the subdomain:

```
get :index
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In test unit i used something like this to set the request.host to come from a subdomain:

```
def get_sub(sub = "one")
  @request.host = "#{sub}.local.me" 
end
```

I personally would put that into the `spec_helper.rb` file and reference when you need.

For you, in those tests, you're setting `sub` to equal `"kong"` probably like

```
before :each do
  get_sub("kong")
end
```

This joker also has an answer too, which i found after [through google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556627/rails-rspec-set-subdomain)

Comment: Why did you call this method `get_sub` when it's clearly setting a value? Also, why shorten it? `set_subdomain` or `stub_subdomain` would be excellent names for this method.

Comment: I guess in the perfect hindsight world, i would have called it `set_subdomain` but pedantic aside, the answer still works. the OP can change the method to whatever he chooses.

Comment: note this will not work in routing specs, as `@request` will be nil