# Need to return JSON-formatted 404 error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a normal HTML frontend and a JSON API in my Rails App. Now, if someone calls `/api/not_existent_method.json` it returns the default HTML 404 page. Is there any way to change this to something like `{"error": "not_found"}` while leaving the original 404 page for the HTML frontend intact?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

A friend pointed me towards a elegant solution that does not only handle 404 but also 500 errors. In fact, it handles every error. The key is, that every error generates an exception that propagates upwards through the stack of rack middlewares until it is handled by one of them. If you are interested in learning more, you can watch [this excellent screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware). Rails has it own handlers for exceptions, but you can override them by the less documented `exceptions_app` config option. Now, you can write your own middleware or you can route the error back into rails, like this:

```
# In your config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

Then you just have to match these routes in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
get "/404" => "errors#not_found"
get "/500" => "errors#exception"
```

And then you just create a controller for handling this.

```
class ErrorsController < ActionController::Base
  def not_found
    if env["REQUEST_PATH"] =~ /^\/api/
      render :json => {:error => "not-found"}.to_json, :status => 404
    else
      render :text => "404 Not found", :status => 404 # You can render your own template here
    end
  end

  def exception
    if env["REQUEST_PATH"] =~ /^\/api/
      render :json => {:error => "internal-server-error"}.to_json, :status => 500
    else
      render :text => "500 Internal Server Error", :status => 500 # You can render your own template here
    end
  end
end
```

One last thing to add: In the development environment, rails usally does not render the 404 or 500 pages but prints a backtrace instead. If you want to see your `ErrorsController` in action in development mode, then disable the backtrace stuff in your `config/enviroments/development.rb` file.

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to add the status code to the renders. Otherwise your client/browser will not know that it was a 404/500.

    render :text => "404 not found", :status => :not_found

Comment: I would say a respond_to block is more universal in the rendering functions:
respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render json: {error: "not-found"}.to_json, status: 404 }
   format.html { render text: "404 Not found", status: 404 }
end

Comment: I've namespaced my API controllers and throw an exception that has a base class like ApiException which can then be rescued in the base namespaced Api controller, where a JSON friendly error can be returned with the appropriate status, like above.

Comment: @RichardHollis My API controllers are namespaced as well but would I achieve what you did?

Comment: @Darksky not sure what you mean?

Comment: @RichardHollis by namespaced did you mean you had them all in a module? If so, how did you create a base class ApiException that handles all errors (including 404 and 500)?

Comment: @Darksky see this Gist - https://gist.github.com/richhollis/6029217 - I mean namespaced in the directory sense

Comment: @RichardHollis Have you ever used rspec to test controllers with a subdomain constraint?

Comment: @Darksky no, but funnily enough I did look into this recently because I project I was working on might have needed sub domains - I found this article which looked promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556627/rails-rspec-set-subdomain

Comment: Rails 4 will give you `You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method` errors with the routes file.

Comment: @iblue How to I handle test for this provided answer

Comment: Check out this answer before resorting to the solution proposed above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29292738/2859525. Its much simpler to just catch 404 in an ancestor controller and use a callback to make a simple JSON error response.

Answer (score 17):

I like to create a separate API controller that sets the format (json) and api-specific methods:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found
  # Use Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound with mongoid

  def not_found
    respond_with '{"error": "not_found"}', status: :not_found
  end
end
```

RSpec test:

```
  it 'should return 404' do
    get "/api/route/specific/to/your/app/", format: :json
    expect(response.status).to eq(404)
  end
```

Comment: This seems to work for records only. How would you manage the case for `api/non_existant_route`?

Comment: the line `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: not_found` needs to be `with: :not_found` but it's only a one character edit :P

Answer (score 11):

Sure, it will look something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from NotFoundException, :with => :not_found
  ...

  def not_found
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :file => File.join(Rails.root, 'public', '404.html') }
      format.json { render :text => '{"error": "not_found"}' }
    end
  end
end
```

`NotFoundException` is *not* the real name of the exception. It will vary with the Rails version and the exact behavior you want. Pretty easy to find with a Google search.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I am using Rails 3.2.2 where the exception handling changed. This will no longer work.

Comment: @iblue This works just fine in Rails 3.2+ and is the better solution. See the `rescue_from` [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

Try to put **at the end** of your `routes.rb`:

```
match '*foo', :format => true, :constraints => {:format => :json}, :to => lambda {|env| [404, {}, ['{"error": "not_found"}']] }
```

Comment: For anyone else reading this, `match` in the `Rails.application.routes` file now requires you to specify the HTTP method, through the `via:` parameter. This will also show up as an error when you attempt to use the above line.