# Rails return all 404 and 500 errors as JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, http

I'm pretty new in rails, and using rails 4.

In my application I want to return all 404 and 500 errors formatted on JSON like that

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "message": "not found"
}
```

There is an easy way to do this ? cause I just find solutions to do this with rails 3.x.

Thanks

I trying to do this solution [Need to return JSON-formatted 404 error in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253366/need-to-return-json-formatted-404-error-in-rails) but I get `error during failsafe response: uninitialized constant ErrorsController`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

May be you're looking for this:

```
render :json => @error_object.to_json, :status => :unprocessable_entity
```

And probably you may catch all standard errors like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from StandardError do |exception|
    # render what you want here
  end
end
```

Comment: probably, but where i have to put that to have JSON render everywhere ?

Comment: worth referencing this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6773038/1571834 to just handle routing errors.