# Embed javascript form 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, api-design

**Context**
I would like to offer a bike rental companies (`shops`) the option to redirect guests to an online reservation process on my platform, so they can let customers make a reservation for a `bike` of the `shop`. *(e.g. online reservation process is just for their shop)*

**Current step**
My first step is to create an embedded javascript form (`form_availability`), where `shop` website visitors can select an `arrival`, `departure` date and subsequently see the available `bike_categories`. To clarify, I would like to show the initial form with arrival and departure options for tthat `shop`.

**Approach**

- I created an `api/v1/shops` (routes, controllers and views)
- I created an `embed.js` using webpacker:vue
- I implemented `<%= javascript_pack_tag "embed" %>` in my own app to test (url: `http://localhost:3000/en/shops/58/website_integration`)
- The `website` of the respective shop is `http://localhost:3000`

**Question**

It's the first time I'm doing this, and I get an error messages I don't know how to deal with/solve.

console

```
embed.js:23 GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shops/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fen%2Fshops%2F3%2Fwebsite_integration/form_availability 500 (Internal Server Error)

./app/javascript/packs/embed.js @ embed.js:23
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
```

```
{type: "NoMethodError", message: "undefined method `url' for ["http://localhost:3000/en/shops/3/website_integration"]:Array", backtrace: Array(76)}

type: "NoMethodError"
message: "undefined method `url' for ["http://localhost:3000/en/shops/3/website_integration"]:Array"
backtrace: (76) ["/Users/robtuinte/code/Tumble25/camping_pms/app/models/shop.rb:41:in `block in <class:Shop>'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/active_record/relation.rb:288:in `instance_exec'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ib/active_record/relation.rb:288:in `_exec_scope'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…e_record/scoping/named.rb:186:in `block in scope'", "/Users/robtuinte/code/Tumble25/camping_pms/app/con…/v1/shops_controller.rb:16:in `form_availability'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…stract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…troller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ctive_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ct_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…nstrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ort/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…tive_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…r/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…r/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge….2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…on_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ction_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…b/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ction_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…n-js-3.5.1/lib/i18n/js/middleware.rb:14:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…s/warden-1.2.8/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ck-2.0.7/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…5.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ck-2.0.7/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…5.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…atch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…0.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…tion_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge….2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…tch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ion_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…tion_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…patch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…b/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…-3.7.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…spatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…s-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge….3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…b/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…b/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…lties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ion_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge….5.0/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…on_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ck-2.0.7/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…e/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…tion_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ction_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…acker/dev_server_proxy.rb:29:in `perform_request'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…s/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…uma-4.1.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…-4.1.0/lib/puma/server.rb:664:in `handle_request'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…-4.1.0/lib/puma/server.rb:467:in `process_client'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…ma-4.1.0/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'", "/Users/robtuinte/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/ge…uma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'"]
__proto__:
```

logs

```
Started GET "/api/v1/shops/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fen%2Fshops%2F3%2Fwebsite_integration/form_availability" for ::1 at 2020-02-18 10:24:21 +0100
Processing by Api::V1::ShopsController#form_availability as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"http://localhost:3000/en/shops/3/website_integration"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**Code**

routes

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :shops, only: [:show] do
        get :form_availability , on: :member
      end
    end
  end
```

controller/api/v1/shops_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::ShopsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def form_availability
    binding.pry
    @shop = Shop.by_url(params[:id])
    render "shops/form_availability"
  end
end
```

models

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bike_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bikes, through: :bike_categories
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy

  def self.by_url(url)
    binding.pry
    uri = url.split("?").first
    uri.sub!(/\/$/, '')

    where(website: uri)
  end
end

class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :bike
end

class Bike < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bike_category
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
end

class BikeCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  has_many :bikes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

javascript/packs/embed.js

````
let url = window.location.href


fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shops/${encodeURIComponent(url)}/form_availability`,{
  headers: {accept: 'application/json'}
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))```

views/api/vi/shop/form_availability.json.jbuilder
````

json.extract! @shop, :id, :name, :slug, :description, :street, :street_number, :zipcode, :city, :country, :email, :phone, :website, :vat_number, :currency, :photo, :test_modus, :default_vat, :price_notation, :paytime, :billing_id, :default_shop_language, :default_age_table, :inv_pay_deadline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing this error, is because the server is responding with a 404 and this is being delivered in HTML rather than JSON format.

You will find some guidance to get error messages in JSON for api requests here (might be helpful for better error handling and debugging):

[Need to return JSON-formatted 404 error in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253366/need-to-return-json-formatted-404-error-in-rails)

The problem why you are getting back a 404 in this particular case though, is that the URL in the `fetch` call is composed incorrectly. There are two issues here:

1. There is a typo - `http://localhost:3000/api/vi/...` - it should be `v1` as defined in your routes, not `vi`.
2. The URI schema in the javascript is composed incorrectly - you can see all available routes per your route definitions by executing `rails routes`. You should be able to find the correct URI pattern in the output - `/api/v1/dummies/:id/form_availability(.:format)` in your case.

So, your embed.js should look something like this:

```
let url = window.location.href


fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shops/${encodeURIComponent(url)}/form_availability`,{
  headers: {accept: 'application/json'}
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

One comment to the class method `self.by_url(url)` that you defined in the `Shop` model. The standard way of doing this, is using scopes (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

So in your model it should be something like this instead of the class method:

```
scope :by_url, ->(url) { where(website: url.split('?').first.sub(/\/$/, '')) }
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I addressed the issues (see question) and consequently obtained a ```500 error```.