# Why is it not possible to use router paths in controller tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, routes

Why is it not possible to use the router paths when testing controllers in Rails 3?

I understand `get :new` translates to `{controller: 'sessions', action: 'new'}`, but why does `signin_path` not translate to the same thing? For example:

```
# routes.rb
match 'signin', to: 'sessions#new'

# sessions_spec.rb
it "renders the 'new' template" do
  get signin_path
  response.should render_template :new
end
```

Produces:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"/signin"}
```

It would be nice if there were way to test routes using the routers syntax as you would inside your application, such as `get signin_path` instead of `{ get: 'http://app.com/signin/' }`

Comment: The syntax should be `match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'` (you left out the leading `/`).

Comment: @cdesrosiers: Not true. But, to be fair, the code you suggest works _also_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had trouble wrapping my head around this at first too. Let me try to explain it how I understand it.

I am assuming that your leading line looks like this:

```
describe SessionsController do
```

In a controller spec, the controller class is your subject, not the routing system. That is why you should be testing individual action methods within your controller, not the routes that lead to them. In other words, the controller spec should still work even if you change your routing.

So you shouldn't even really be doing this:

```
it "renders the 'new' template" do
  get 'http://app.com/signin/'
  response.should render_template :new
end
```

You should be doing this:

```
it "renders the 'new' template" do
  get :new
  response.should render_template :new
end
```

RSpec then somehow figures out which route you are trying to hit. I've noticed that when I botch something, it gives me a routing error.

Comment: As a side note, if you want to run tests involving the routing `*_path` helpers, you can do "integration" (aka "request") specs. They are different than controller specs.

Comment: That makes sense. To be fair, I was already testing along those lines. What tripped me up was subdomain constrained routes. I want to be sure, for example, that going through `signup_path` with a subdomain has a different consequence when not using a subdomain. Using `get :whatever` bypasses the router, so the expectations change. I ended up moving those tests to the requests specs.

Comment: @Mohamad: I figured, but I wanted to be clear in the answer. Take a look at this approach to changing the domain in controller specs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556627/rails-rspec-set-subdomain

Comment: My approach is slightly different though: `def set_controller_host(host) before { @request.host = host }; end` Sorry about crappy comment formatting of the code; that's why I made it a one-liner!

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your routes.rb

`match 'signin' => 'sessions#new', :as => :signin`