# Rspec controller testing - unexpected errors/not sure how to handle it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I use this tests for `FacultiesController`:

```
describe FacultiesController do
  describe "GET show" do
    it "responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code" do
      get :show
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

Failures:

```
  1) FacultiesController GET show responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code
     Failure/Error: get :show

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"faculties"}
     # ./spec/controllers/faculties_controller_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) FacultiesController GET index responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code
     Failure/Error: @faculties=Faculty.where(:university_id => @university.id).all

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/faculties_controller.rb:5:in `index'
     # ./spec/controllers/faculties_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

1) When I run `rake routes` I see

```
faculty GET    /faculties/:shortcut(.:format)                      faculties#show
```

So, I suppose I need to specify shortcut with this GET. But how?

I tried add `:shortcut=>"test"`, but this didn't work, also tried `params: {:shortcut=>"test"}`. Nothing works until I just write `"GET faculties/test"` and **also remove line** `get :show`.

Is that as it should to be?

2)

```
Failure/Error: @faculties=Faculty.where(:university_id => @university.id).all

         NoMethodError:
           undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

First of all, it, again, work just fine in browser testing. I use module which helps controller to define `@university` by subdomain.

How can I pass this to test? Should I just provide some option to get index? By the way, it is all defined in my `factories.rb` file, as subdomain string is stored in db.

I though may be I should invoke factories new instance in this spec before `describe`?

```
university = create(:university)
faculty = create(:faculty)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should create a new faculty and pass it's id

```
describe "GET show" do
  let(:faculty) {FactoryGirl.create(:faculty)}
  it "responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code" do
     get :show, :id => faculty.id #or get :show, :shortcut => faculty.id
    expect(response).to be_success
    expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
  end
end
```

2) You should create faculty & university & pass it as params

```
describe "GET index" do
  let(:university) {FactoryGirl.create(:university)}
  before(:each) do
    FactoryGirl.create(:faculty, :university_id => university.id)  
  end 
  it "responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code" do
    get :index, university_id => university.id
    expect(response).to be_success
    expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
  end
end
```

Please provide index route if it wouldn't work

Comment: first part is right, but on the second it is same error

Comment: ok, I found here solution [Sof-magic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556627/rails-rspec-set-subdomain) Please give more information on why you use "let" and "before" and I'll accept

Comment: let is very convenient for rspec tests. It will create a record on demand (it will not create a record if you do not use it in particular test). This leads to faster specs. Here it's some docs https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-3/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let . I propose to create university & faculty to have better spec (if you test without data to render - it can render only part of the page and you and up with passed spec, but possible error in production). I use let for university because it used in spec body and create faculty in before(:each) because it is not used in spec body